# Zend Framework how to set headers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a question, how can I do something like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf"); 
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
```

With Zend Framework, I have tried:

```
        $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition:inline', ' filename=result.pdf')
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf');
```

But doesn't work correctly.

Comment: The correct Mime-Type for PDF is application/pdf.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your statement to set the response headers is slightly malformed:

```
$this->getResponse()
     ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=result.pdf')
     ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf');
```

The above should work - please note the difference in the `Content-Disposition`-header.

By the way... When you want to force a download box (instead of loading the document in the browser) you should use the `Content-Disposition` `attachment`.

```
$this->getResponse()
     ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=result.pdf')
     ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf');
```

Depending on the browser it may be possible that you also have to set the `Content-Length` or change the `Content-type` to a combination (multiple headers) of one or more of `application/force-download`, `application/octet-stream` and/or `application/download`. And as I wrote in the comment sometimes caching headers may interfere with your download. Check to see which caching-headers are sent.

Comment: You're example doesn't work SR, i don't receive the download box anymore.Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/d6be142ab

Comment: Which browser? And can you check what headers are actually sent over the wire? Especially some caching-headers may interfer with file-downloads.

Comment: @Uffo: If you want to force a download, you should say so in your question. You only asked what the correct way to set the headers is, and S. Gehrig's original reply was just that.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the table, I can recommend [this action helper](https://github.com/noginn/noginn/blob/master/Noginn/Controller/Action/Helper/SendFile.php) as a simple, reusable component for sending files or in memory data to the browser.

Has options for caching, disposition and can utilise Apache Sendfile

Comment: Link is dead; any alternatives?

Comment: @Aron see http://github.com/noginn/noginn/blob/master/Noginn/Controller/Action/Helper/SendFile.php

Comment: Nice one, but this should not read whole file at once, but part-by-part. For big files it is an overkill.

Comment: It can utilise Apache Sendfile which is much more efficient, if available

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're doing something like:

```
$this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition:inline', ' filename=result.pdf')
        ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf');
fpassthru($filename);
exit();
```

or something.

The response here will never be rendered (which renders the headers).  The response is rendered during post-action printing, usually.

You will have to directly set the headers (as you noted in the non-oo code), or use `$this->getResponse()->sendHeaders()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a header set.
It was not set, but ADDED.
So I had a Content-Type of text/html and also application/pdf.

Flagging the Content-Type with TRUE made the download possible in IOS and other devices which showed only cryptic symbols after the download or an error:

`->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf', true);`

`setHeader($name, $value, $replace = false)`

from:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.controller.response.html

Answer (score -5):

Solved

```
        $this->getResponse()
         ->setHeader('Content-Disposition:inline', ';filename=result.pdf')
             ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-pdf');
```

Comment: Look at S. Gehrig's answer, it's the correct one. Yours may work, but only incidentally. ":inline" is not a part of the name of the header.