# Download pdf file from a string using Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, zend-framework

All,

I have a PHP5 application written with Zend Framework and MVC. On my home page, I want to incorporate the functionality to download a dynamically generated pdf file. The way this is done is:

1. User clicks "download file" link.
2. On Click, an AJAX call occurs to a PHP controller, which takes the form data, generates the pdf and returns it as a string.
3. My javascript function now has the pdf string.
4. How can I display the user an "Open/Save" dialog to download the pdf file from javascript?

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
   $('#dlcontent').click(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/downloads/dlpolicies",
                data:  $("#frmMyContent").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html_input){
                    alert(html_input);  // This has the pdf file in a string.
                    //ToDo: Open/Save pdf file dialog using this string..
                }
            });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try to keep this simple. Just sumbit the form with a `target="_blank"` and then have PHP force the file download.

**HTML CODE**

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
$('#dlcontent').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#frmMyContent").submit();
});
</script>

<form id="formMyContent" action="/downloads/dlpolicies" target="_blank" ... >
...
</form>
```

Then on your server side, you need to tell PHP to send the response as a "download".

**PHP Code**

```
$this->getResponse()
  ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=result.pdf')
  ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
```

Got this from here:
[Zend Framework how to set headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326270/zend-framework-how-to-set-headers)

Comment: hmm..How do i force the pdf string into result.pdf?

Comment: The content-type should be "application/pdf", as it was standardized quite a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it is open a new window with URL to pdf string.

Answer (score 0):

Add an element to your page where you want the link to go. It can be a span or a div or a cell in a table or whatever you want.  Give it a unique ID.  Then use jQuery to set the html of that element.  I refer to it as `somepageelement` here.

```
$('#dlcontent').click(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/downloads/dlpolicies",
                data:  $("#frmMyContent").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html_input){
                    $('#somepageelement').html('<a href="' + html_input + '">Click here to download the pdf</a>');
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: The issue is "#dlcontent" itself is a link to download the pdf file. Can i do it through a pop up window? With this I don't have to click 2 links to download a file.

Comment: @vincent Ah okay, sorry for the misunderstanding.  In that case I'm not sure why you need Ajax to do this.  I would have a form that posts to a page that generates the pdf and specify the `target="_new"` on the form so it opens in a new window.  If you want you can make it so that clicking on `#dlcontent` submits the form.