# Can $.getJSON() get PDF/Docx in Save Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

```
 $.getJSON( 
     dUrl,
     data:'{ a: 2, b: 3 }',
     function(data){alert(data);}
      });
```

Will making a $.getJSON() request be able to pop up the pdf/docx in a new window? if yes, could you please share more info on this..

I'm getting the pdf/docx file from Response stream into Fiddler.
But need to find a way to push it to **Save As** Dialog box.

Any help is appreciated...

Here is the Custom ActionResult

```
public class DownloadResult : ActionResult
    {

        public DownloadResult()
        {
        }
        public DownloadResult(string virtualPath)
        {
            this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
        }

        public string VirtualPath
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string FileDownloadName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {


            //context.HttpContext.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
            //context.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            //context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            // Response.BinaryWrite(content)
            //Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
            //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            string filePath = this.VirtualPath;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                string contentType = "";
                if (filePath.ToLower().Contains(".pdf"))
                    contentType = "application/pdf";
                else
                    contentType = "application/msword";

                context.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
                context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileDownloadName))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + this.FileDownloadName);
                }
                context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
        }
}
```

Controller's Action :

```
 public ActionResult DownloadDocument(string uri)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
            {

                string targetPath = ConfigurationHelper.GetFolderPath("TempStoreFolder");

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetPath))
                {
                    targetPath.LogDebug("[TempStoreFolder] setting is not defined in the configuration");
                    return null; 
                }
                uri = Path.Combine(targetPath, uri);

                var downloadResult = new DownloadResult
                {
                    VirtualPath = uri,
                    FileDownloadName = uri
                };
                return downloadResult;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#frmdownloadDocuments").attr('action',dUrl);
$("#frmdownloadDocuments").submit();
```

Simple Form Submit from [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320609/download-pdf-file-from-a-string-using-jquery/3320748#3320748) gets me the Response as Download dialog.

I shouldn't have used `$.getJSON()` request to download PDF.

Answer (score 1):

`window.open('http://yoursite.com/my.pdf')`

Comment: I'm sending this PDF document as a Stream thru Response Stream.
How can I capture the stream? and display Save As dialog..

Comment: add `Content-disposition: attachment` to the headers you send back, that tells the browser its a file to save, not content.