# How do I set/change content-type headers for an entire Zend Framework Application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've already seen this question: 
[Zend Framework how to set headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326270/zend-framework-how-to-set-headers)
and I am aware of how to set headers on a per controller basis.

`$this->getResponse()
     ->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')`

However i'd like to set the content-header in my config file and have it set all my responses to use that content type. Is there some built in method/convention I'm missing out on? I'll settle for setting something in the bootstrap as 2nd best choice.

This is in my config:

```
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8"
```

and I'm using modules and layouts if its any help (default module in this case)

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a plugin for this which automatically sets the content-type to a default when no other content-types have been set already. Example:

```
class YourApp_Controller_Plugin_ContentType extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $http_headers = $response->getHeaders();

        /**
         * Check whether the Content-Type header is defined.
         */
        $content_type_found = false;
        foreach ($http_headers as $_header)
        {
            if ($_header['name'] === 'Content-Type')
            {
                $content_type_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        /**
         * When no Content-Type has been set, set the default text/html; charset=utf-8
         */
        if (!$content_type_found)
        {
            $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first I thought the plugin method was a little odd, but having tried it out it seems to work well. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for checking if the header was already set. Since `setHeader()` will by default leave existing header with the same name without replacing.

```php
class YourApp_Controller_Plugin_ContentType extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        /**
         * When no Content-Type has been set, set the default text/html; charset=utf-8
         */
        $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if `$replace === false`, Zend will add (by default) the header even if already exists and you will have duplicate header names.

```
    if ($replace) {
        foreach ($this->_headers as $key => $header) {
            if ($name == $header['name']) {
                unset($this->_headers[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_headers[] = array(
        'name'    => $name,
        'value'   => $value,
        'replace' => $replace
    );
```