# Php - how can i echo this variable as jpeg

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

In Php (zend framework 1.x) i am printing the RAW value `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA....` . And trying to preview it in a

But when loading the JPEG as link its failing, Content Type: image/html instead of image/jpeg.

In PHP i set the content type to image/jpeg but its not applying. How to solve it?

```
  public function getpreviewAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();
    $data = (object) $post;
    $this->db = Application_Model_Db::db_load();

    $sql = "select *from sh_av_profile where
              username='{$data->username}'
        limit 1";

    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
    if (count($result) > 0) {
      //echo "<img src={$result[0]['preview']} />";
      echo $result[0]['preview'];         
    }    

    exit;
  }
```

Js:

```
  function previewRender() {
    var root = $('img');
    //root.attr('src',lasturl +"?"+ Date.parse(new Date().toString()) );      

    root.attr('src', 'http://pbx/ajax/getpreview?username=T1');      
  }
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:18844
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 31 Jan 2014 07:06:14 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=70
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2
```

Comment: getpicture in the src and getpreviewAction in zend? Are you sure the method you posted is called?

Comment: Is anything printed before `getpreviewAction()` is called? Any response forces the headers to be sent, thus changing the headers after they are sent will do nothing (as you can see in your example).

Comment: It was paste mistake. it should be getpreview and still the same problem.

Comment: @styfle: from _helper and _response nothing is printed those are the start

Comment: What about something like this: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: I have never used zend but the syntax from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1326270/266535) looks different then what you wrote. Maybe try `getResponse()`?

Comment: I used getResponse, but that also do not worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `base64_decode` first and then `echo` the variable.

Also, if you just `exit`, then `setHeader` won't probably work. So just do `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')` before you `echo`.

Edit:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo base64_decode( $result[0]['preview'] );
exit();
```

Comment: Tried like you mentioned but still not working. e.g: echo "data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_decode($raw); or echo base64_decode($raw); or header(.. still not getting JPEG

Comment: Check the edit. Assuming that `$result[0]['preview']` is base64 encoded string, it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: YES - its a base64-encoded string, but exactly like you shown i have applied, and still its not working. My string is as "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA.... long.." i have also tried by making it in two part such as data:image/jpeg;base64, and another part with all the random encrypted values and then also used with base64_decode those two parts. But still same no luck yet.

Comment: Remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,` then try it.